# creating an algorithm/formula to rotate ad's on a site

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, ads

I'm looking to rotate ad's on a site but I want to come up with a formula that takes into consideration the following:

- Timestamp (more recently created ad's should have high priority)
- Number of impressions (Those ads with less views should have high priority). Ideally, I would like to set a quota for number of impressions per month for every ad.
- A weight (Those ads with high weight should have high priority)

And then at the end I would like to some how randomize the results. What will be the best way to accomodate these factors into a PHP script or a mysql query ? So far I have tried a query like this:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM banner_ads  WHERE usedImpressions/totalImpressions < $threshold OR usedImpressions = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

But ofcourse the big limitation here is what should be a good value for the threshold and it still doesn't take into consideration the weight or timestamp at which it was created.

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking for just a query, but the pseudocode / math solution is:

First Calculate a weighting for each ad:

```
 CurrentWeight = BaseWeight 
               + AdPriority 
               - Impressions*ImpressionWeight 
               - (CurrentDate-CreateDate)*DateWeight;
```

Then each of your ads would have a percentage of the whole chance of being picked:

```
 PerAdPercentage = CurrentWeight / Sum(allCurrentWeightsAllAds)
```

Use that percentage to assign a block of numbers to each ad (e.g. 0-100). Now use a random number generator to pick a number in that range and select a winner.

To handle quota either:

1. Remove it from the list of Current ads included in the search or,
2. Add in another weight to heavily discount it if over the quota.

I also add a value to prioritize ads furthest from their quota as well.

Re: Your comment:

The current weight should calculate all the things you want to matter about how often you show an ad. Then you compare the calculated weights to each other to determine the relative priority of each ad. When each ad has a block of numbers depending on it's relative weighting you will hit more often on ones which have higher weightings than ones with less.

The ImpressionWeight and DateWeight are arbitrary numbers you use to balance/tune the equation to factor in an appropriate value to your weight - basically normalize the numbers. (e.g. say you do your date math in milliseconds and get huge numbers, but use 1-10 for your AdPriority - these numbers are meaningless if combined without weighting the date value to make it a very small number as well)

Finally you likely want to consider max values from which Date and Impressions can subtract from the overall weighting, as you likely do not want to drive the percentage/weighting to zero. For date you may want something which decays non-linearly.

Comment: What would be impression weight and date weight fields ? Also, if I pick a random number between 0 to 100 then it wouldn't prioritize the ones that have a higher perAdpercentage which is what I want..isn't that correct ?

Comment: Addressed your comments in the answer

Comment: Ok but if you pick a random number between 0 to 100, you could technically pick 0 too. So shouldn't I have a threshold like 75 for example ?

Comment: The scale doesn't matter as long as something that has a 50% chance of being picked gets 50% of the range of numbers used when calculating a random value.

Comment: How would it get 50% of the range of numbers though ? Each ad will have its own percentage value. Ad A can have 10%, Ad B can have 20%, Ad C can have 30%, Ad D can have 40% etc. Doing a rand can pick either ad a, b, c or d. D wont be prioritized over  A, B or C.

Comment: Your Example: You define a range from 1-100 and choose a random number. You have three ads to choose from A(10%), B(40%) and C(50%). Just give each a portion of the range based on their percentage: (whole number example for ease) A gets 1 to 10, B get 11-50, C get 51-100. The random number will be 5x more likely to fall between 51 and 100 than between 1 and 10.

Comment: There is a start date and end date for every add so if I do something like this : (CurrentDate - StartDate/ EndDate - StartDate) * 10, would that be a good way to scale the date factor between 0 to 10 ? What do you think ?

Comment: 0-10 is an example - you should keep the numbers arbitrary as it does not really matter - what matters is tuning the weights of each variable so that the magnitude of each factor makes sense to the equation. You will likely want to play with the numbers a bit to make the results look the way you want (I would run mockups to see all ads are being appropriately distributed over time, etc).